# HTML Page from selected row in Spotfire

Tags: analytics, ironpython, tibco, spotfire, terr

I have come across a requirement that is already available in the current tool and they expect it to be implemented in Spotfire as well.

Requirement: Once data is loaded in Spotfire and they click on a row, there is a button "View in Web" that will render that selected row in a beautiful static HTML page in a new window.

My Logic so far: I'll store the column values in variables using ironpyton as explained in https://techgoje.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/spotfire-ironpython-accessing-column-values-in-script-context/ and then i'll render those values in HTML page

Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to open a popup or new window in Spotfire. my guess is that you could do it in the Web Player, but it may not work in the thick client.

I've created [an example DXP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18835606/Javascript%20and%20IronPython%20Interaction.dxp) that shows how IronPython and Javascript can interact to render HTML content in a textarea. this may be a good solution for you.

(**NOTE**: you will need to trust all of the IP and JS scripts in this document!)

Comment: That's a very cool stuff Niko..thanks a lot for your help...:) Although i have implemented Jquery and JS in my analysis but this is so cool..thanks again...will you mind if i can email you my doubts on your email id ? :)

Comment: I've found that using IronPython to open a new Tab/Window is possible in the Spotfire Application, but will not work when deployed for use in the WebPlayer.